# Need a code to transcribe in an exotic language

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm from Ukraine. I need to transcribe podcasts in Ukrainian. Please tell me the code to start transcription in Ukrainian. I tried to find the code myself. For this purpose I even generated a code, but it turned out that it was not correct. So, I tried these options:

1. !whisper "ENTER FILE NAME HERE" --model medium.ua
2. !whisper "ENTER FILE NAME HERE" --model medium --language ua
3. print(transcribe_ukrainian('Hello, light!')) - this one was generated. In it ('Hello, light!') is the file name.
   All three options didn't work
   Thank you in advance